# LiteIDE debug go code on mac

Tags: macos, debugging, osx-mavericks, liteide

today I installed LiteIDE on my mac with OSX 10.9. I tried to compile simple source code and it worked fine, however debugger doesn't work because of missing GDB. I installed it from MacPorts, changed darwin64.env file, and now LiteIDE runs debugger and shows tabs with variables, call stack and etc, but they are empty and I can't run my code line to line! If I click Debug->Continue or Debug->Step Over nothing changes. There is my darwin64.env file:

```
# native compiler drawin amd64

GOROOT=/usr/local/go
#GOBIN=
GOARCH=amd64
GOOS=darwin
CGO_ENABLED=1

PATH=$GOROOT/bin:$PATH

LITEIDE_GDB=/opt/local/bin/ggdb
LITEIDE_MAKE=make
LITEIDE_TERM=/usr/bin/open
LITEIDE_TERMARGS=-a Terminal
LITEIDE_EXEC=/usr/X11R6/bin/xterm
LITEIDE_EXECOPT=-e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a solution. My ggdb, which was downloaded via MacPorts was unsigned. You must create a key in your keychain to allow ggdb sign code

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

brew install https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/master/gdb.rb